# Проблема: сервер генерит новый файл только при перезапуске (а должен - по запросу)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, веб-сервер, кэширование

Есть цепочка "**HTML+скрипт**" -> "**сервер на NodeJS+Express**(*локалхост*)" -> **API озвучки текста** ->**получение звукового файла + сохранение в папку сервера** -> **воспроизведение в браузере**.

По замыслу, при нажатии кнопки на странице, на сервер уходит запрос, а сервер делает запрос к API.
API возвращает уникальный(т.е. новое содержимое каждый раз) **.ogg-файл**, который сохраняется на серве, и далее он должен произнестись вслух в браузере.

**Вот HTML:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка **GenerateAndSay** делает запрос к адресу **/directFetch**, который призван сгенерить файл и сохранить его.
Также добавлена кнопка **ClearOldFIle**, ведущая на адрес **/deleter**, где прописано удаление файла.

**Вот код скрипта для кнопок:**

```html
let $clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton")
let $genAndSayButton = document.getElementById("generateAndSay")

$clearButton.onclick = function(){
    alert('removing')
    fetch(`http://localhost:3333/deleter`, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
        .then(response => alert(response.status))
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
$genAndSayButton.onclick = function(){
    alert('clicked')
    fetch(`http://localhost:3333/directFetch`, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
        .then(response => alert(response.status))
        .then(response => {
            let realSound = new Audio(`./file.ogg`);
            realSound.volume = 1.0;
            realSound.play();
        })
}
```

**Вот тело кода сервера - та часть, что относится к проблеме:**

```html
const port = process.env.PORT||3333;

    app.get('/index', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    app.use(express.static(path.join('./')));

    app.get('/directFetch', (req, res) => {
        console.log('direct Fetch consoling') //не работает на хероку

  //-------------------fetch to API and receiving a file-----------------------
        fetch('https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize', {
            method: 'post',
            body: params,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Api-Key ' + api_key,
            },
        })
            .then(resp => {
                const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`./file.ogg`);
                resp.body.pipe(dest);

     //---this small block i used to see files on Heroku------
                let ar = []
                fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(file => {
                    ar.push(file);
                })
                res.send(ar)
       //-----------small block finished------------------
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
    //-----------------remover address-------
    app.get('/deleter', function(req, res) {
        fs.access(`${__dirname}/file.ogg`, function(error){
            if (error) {
                console.log("Файл не найден аксес");
            } else {
                console.log("Файл найден аксес и щас удалим");
                fs.unlinkSync(`${__dirname}/file.ogg`); //должен удалить файло
                console.log("Файл должен был удалиться");
            }
        });
    })
    
    app.use(express.static(path.join('./')));

    app.listen(port);
```

**Суть ПРОБЛЕМЫ:** при нажатии кнопки удаления, файл физически исчезает из папки, далее нажимаю кнопку генерации - генерируется (и воспроизводится) новый файл с ***прежним*** содержимым (а должно быть каждый раз новое).
Для генерации нового файла с ***новым*** содержимым приходится перезапускать сервер.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я накосячил в коде.
Напомню, сервер - локалхост. Браузер Хром, в других не пробовал.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что такое `params` в строчке `body : params`, и где эта переменная определяется и изменяется?

Comment: @Yaant
_Это одна из нескольких переменных для запроса от Сервера к АПИ:_
const { URLSearchParams } = require('url');
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('text', text);
params.append('voice', 'alena');
params.append('emotion', 'neutral');
params.append('lang', 'ru-RU');
params.append('speed', '1.0');
params.append('format', 'oggopus');

Comment: Так я к тому, что судя по коду, Вы нигде не изменяете эти параметры, поэтому, вызывая API с одними и теми же параметрами, Вы ожидаемо получаете в ответ один и тот же звуковой файл.

Comment: @Yaant нет-нет, за содержимое отвечает переменная text, рандомно генерируемая отдельным скриптом. Если перезапустить серв вручную, то файл успешно пересоздаётся.

Comment: Так вот в том-то и вопрос, точно ли она перегенерируется перед каждым обращением к API? Потому что больше в приведенном коде ничего подозрительного вроде бы не видно.

Comment: @Yaant мыслите верно... перенёс вызов функции генерации прямо в тело запроса `app.get /`, толку нет((( хотя ниже в том же файле-коде сервера отдельно вызываю эти же функции, и при запуске файла исправно выдают разные результаты, как и положено